# Git-commit message editor built-in intellij's terminal - how to set it up as default commit text editor?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, text, editor, commit

Once I had a problem with this built-in commit text editor so I had to change it to Atom or Sublime Text editor.

And my question is: Is there any possibility to set-up this Intellij's built-in commit text editor as default commit editor? So when I type "git commit" in Intellij's terminal, I would be able to write commit message right in this terminal? not in external program. If yes, teach me master, how :)

I really love this terminal, so I don't want any alternatives :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal itself is not an editor, you still need to start some editor like vim or nano to edit commit message. Such editors will work in the terminal though, so you just need to edit your git config either to point to some editor of your choice or just use the default - vim (removing the core.editor value from config should).